# Image links change to an image that exists

Tags: php, html, image

This is a really bizarre issue that I've been having.

It happens to images that seem to have a name that is similar to something else.
For instance, if I have an image named `image0001.png` and I try to display an image with the source of `image0010.png` - which doesn't exist - then the image does not display as nothing, or fire onerror image, instead it displays as `image0001.png` which does exist.

I have no idea how to to fix this because I don't really know what is going on.

I am using the following code to fetch results from the database and produce a table with item details.

```
<?php while ($row = $retval->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/path/to/item/<?= $row['id']; ?>.php"><?= $row['id']; ?></a>
        </td>
        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/path/to/item/<?= $row['id']; ?>.php">
                <img src="/images/<?= $row['id']; ?>.jpg" onerror="this.src='/images/error.png';">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td><?= $row['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well the question is, where do you store the images, how do you display, some code how you store and re-get the intel would be nice..

Comment: Start by showing some examples just plain text isn't much to work with I'm afraid. Do you have the code which generates the HTML for the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like mod_speling is enabled on your server.

> Requests to documents sometimes cannot be served by the core apache server because the request was misspelled or miscapitalized. This module addresses this problem by trying to find a matching document, even after all other modules gave up.

[Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html)

You can try to disable this apache module in a .htaccess file:

```
CheckSpelling Off
```

Comment: Yes, I use 1and1 for hosting and I have uploaded the .htaccess file with CheckSpelling Off on the server (through FTP) but the error still persists.  Hmmmm

Comment: It is quite possible that the server configuration does not allow to change the option in a .htaccess file.

Comment: 3.5 years later and still need this answer. If only I could upvote again!

Answer (score 0):

The obvious other alternative is to use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), removing the reliance of JavaScript and ensuring that the image is shown if it exists or an error image if not.

```
<?php while ($row = $retval->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='/path/to/item/<?= $row['id']; ?>.php'><?= $row['id']; ?></a>
        </td>
        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
        <td>
            <a href='/path/to/item/<?= $row['id']; ?>.php'>
                <?php if (file_exists("/images/{$row['id']}.jpg")) { ?>
                    <img src="/images/<?= $row['id']; ?>.jpg" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="/images/error.png" />
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td><?= $row['description']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```